# translating a div on hover does not work anymore when put in a flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have two rectangles with a background effect. On their own, the hover function works well and translates the top div up and to the right, however I soon as I put this code into a flex container, the hover does not work anymore. Anybody know why? Heres the code without the flex container:

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.box2:hover {
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box2">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Add display: flex; to the body afterwards and the code wont work anymore.

Comment: Remove `z-index: -1;` The element is dropped behind the body

Comment: Make the z-index higher.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try, I delete the z-index.

```css
body {
        padding: 100px;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        
    }

    .box {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: black;
        border: solid 2px black;
        border-radius: 15px;
        
        display: inline-block;
        
    }
    .box2 {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        left: 2px;
        bottom: 5px;
        background-color: white;
        border: solid 2px black;
        border-radius: 15px;    
    }

    .box2:hover {
        left: 8px;
        bottom: 4px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">
      <div class="box2">
      </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOVerflow! Please **explain your code**.  Nobody knows what you're doing when you just send code. "Try this" answers aren't helpful for beginners because it doesn't tell them how the code works, and what to do if they have errors. Please edit with a simple code explanation. Read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer